# Google Script to take a Google Form's results and fill out another form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm not a programmer, but have copied and pasted other scripts together to email some forms upon submission.

If one answer on a google form is true I would like to take some of that submission's results and fill out another google form I have created.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Here is an example of code I've pieced together to email the results of one our forms upon submission.

```
    function sendFormByEmail(e) {
  var email = "xyxy@yyy.com";
    var subject = "Practice Referral Form";
  var msgHtml = e.values[5] + "," + "<br/> <br/> <br/>"
        + "Your instructor has referred you to practice the content/skills below. =" + "<br/>"
        + "<h1><b>Referral Information:</b></h1>"
        + "<b>Instructor:  </b> " + e.values[1] + "<br/>"
        + "<b>Instructor Email:  </b> " + e.values[2] + "<br/>"  
        + "<b>Date:  </b> " + e.values[0] + "<br/>"        
        + "<b>Required Content/Skills:  </b> " + e.values[3] + "<br/>"
        + "<b>Skills must be completed by:  </b> " + e.values[4] + "<br/>"
        + "<br/> <br/> "
        + "<b>Student Name: </b>" + e.values[5] + "<br/>"
        + "<br/> "



    var bccList = e.values[6];
  var optAdvancedArgs = {bcc: bccList, noReply: true, htmlBody: msgHtml};
    var msgPlain = msgHtml.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); // clear html tags and convert br to new lines for plain mail
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msgPlain, optAdvancedArgs);
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code you've created using the other scripts.You cannot fill out a second google form, but you can definitely add a row to the other form's spreadsheet, which is equivalent to filling up the form

Comment: It is possible to create a link to a pre-filled form filled with whatever data you want, but not, AFAIK to actually submit it.  As @Srik says, you can also write data directly to a spreadsheet in lieu of using a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks straighforward. And the change you need is also straightforward. try something like this....

```
    function sendFormByEmail(e) {
      var email = "xyxy@yyy.com";
        var subject = "Practice Referral Form";
      var msgHtml = e.values[5] + "," + "<br/> <br/> <br/>"
            + "Your instructor has referred you to practice the content/skills below. =" + "<br/>"
            + "<h1><b>Referral Information:</b></h1>"
            + "<b>Instructor:  </b> " + e.values[1] + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Instructor Email:  </b> " + e.values[2] + "<br/>"  
            + "<b>Date:  </b> " + e.values[0] + "<br/>"        
            + "<b>Required Content/Skills:  </b> " + e.values[3] + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Skills must be completed by:  </b> " + e.values[4] + "<br/>"
            + "<br/> <br/> "
            + "<b>Student Name: </b>" + e.values[5] + "<br/>"
            + "<br/> "



        var bccList = e.values[6];
      var optAdvancedArgs = {bcc: bccList, noReply: true, htmlBody: msgHtml};
        var msgPlain = msgHtml.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""); // clear html tags and convert br to new lines for plain mail
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msgPlain, optAdvancedArgs);

/* Write to the second spreadsheet */ 
var NEWSSID = 'ID_OF_THE_SECOND_FORM_SPREADSHEET'; 
// Assuming  e.values[3] is what you're checking
if (e.values[3].toLowerCase() == 'true'){
  var values = ['','','','',''] ; // Fill up with values you want to fill up in the new spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(NEWSSID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName'); //Replace name of the sheet here
  var row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; 
  sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
}

    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked great.  Is there anyway to trigger the first script when a new row gets added to the spread sheet?